# MIDI connection to tablet not working

Tags: piano, midi, keyboard

I am trying to connect my tablet (Samsung galaxy tab a 10.1 2019) to my piano keyboard (Yamaha P-70) using a midi cable.
The keyboard is connected to the tablet through the midi cable and a USB b to USB c adapter.
I tried a simple sight-reading app that shows a sequence of notes to play at the right time and the problem is that the communication of the MIDI signal works perfectly for the first input (the first note pressed), but every input after that is not recognized at all.
I also tried a virtual keyboard app and I get the same problem,but i also noticed that every note pressed after the first stay pressed forever.
I find this behavior quite strange because there is communication between tablet and keyboard, but for some reason it doesn't work.
I would like to know if someone had the same problem and he solved it.
Thanks

Comment: First check to be made is, whether the interface works from a real PC. Tablet USB ports are typically more capable than those of digital pianos but may still not support everything.

Comment: Thans for the suggestion i'll try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, running status does not work in your setup.

This is a known bug of the CH345 chip, which is used mainly in cheap Chinese USB/MIDI interfaces like this:
[image: no-name MIDI interface with CH345]

Comment: That was the first cable i tried then after reading that wasnt good i bought another one that looked better quality but always chinese. Do you have any suggestion about a good quality cable?

Comment: Well-known brands, such as ESI, iConnectivity, M-Audio, Miditech, Roland.

Comment: I bought a roland cable and it works very well so thank you for the answer. For those who are interested my current setup is cable: roland um one tablet: samsung galaxy tab a 2019 keyboard: Yamaha p70