# MIDI connection between drum kit and laptop not working

Tags: drums, midi, drum-kits, electronic-drumset

I have an electronic drum kit (Millenium MPS-100) connected to my laptop via a MIDI (5-pin) to USB cable (just a cheap cable, there's no brand/model on it). I can't seem to get any signal from the drum kit to my laptop. I'm using MIDI-OX to check the raw input, and its only sending an 'active sensing' command. When I hit the snare hard enough it also sends a 'timing clock' command (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot from midi-ox]

This is the only signal I've gotten so far. I've tried another MIDI to USB cable (same type, but a second one), and nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong? Or is the MIDI output port of my drum kit just broken?

Edit:

There are three LEDs on the converter: power, in and out. The power LED is on, and the in LED is flashing when an active sensing command is sent. When I hit any drum/cymbal, the LED flashes an extra time. Maybe this info is useful.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. pick one & stick to it, or request migration. - https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48318/midi-connection-between-drum-kit-and-laptop-not-working

Comment: Is your converter a broken one like [this one](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95008/midi-connection-to-tablet-not-working/95015#95015)?

Comment: @Tetsujin i'm sorry, i later realised i should've posted on the sound design SE.

Comment: @CL. Yup, that's the one. So I should just buy a better midi cable?

Comment: tbh, it's probably a better fit for here than Sound Design. It's a) more a hardware/computer issue than actual sound construction & b) this stack is busier.

Comment: @sFyX67v7Ia1XDGFU Yes; pretty much any other one would actually work.